# Getting execution time from QueryDatabaseTable in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using the process QueryDatabaseTable in NiFi for incrementally getting data from a DB2. QueryDatabaseTable is scheduled to run every 5 minutes. Maximum-value Columns is set to "rep" (which corresponds to a date, in the DB2 db).

I have a seperate MySQL database I want to update with the value "rep", that QueryDatabaseTable uses to query the DB2 database with. How can i get this value?

In the logfiles I've found that the attributes of the FlowFiles does not contain this value.

Answer (score 1):

QueryDatabaseTable doesn't currently accept incoming flow files or allow the use of Expression Language to define the table name, I've written up an improvement Jira to handle this:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2340

Comment: What i want is the value of "rep", that QueryDatabaseTable saves as a state (ie. the LAST value it has queried for).
I've thought about making a custom process for this task, and add the 
State of QueryDatabaseTable (the max value) to an attribute according to https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/QueryDatabaseTable.java line 250 - I just don't like that solution. Are the "State" of a process avaliable to me to reference somehow?

Comment: The state itself isn't available. I've added another improvement Jira to add the observed max values as attributes: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2641